# 3D range reference in phpspreadsheet

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I have the following functions to generate Conditional expressions using PHPSpreadsheet:

```
public function conditionAequalsB($a,$b,$cell,$color = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_GREEN,$setBold = true){
    $objConditional = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Conditional();
    $objConditional->setConditionType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Conditional::CONDITION_EXPRESSION);
    echo '='.$a.'='.$b.'<br>';
    $objConditional->addCondition('='.$a.'='.$b);
    $objConditional->getStyle()->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB($color);
    $objConditional->getStyle()->getFont()->setBold($setBold);

    $this->addConditions($cell,$objConditional);
}

public function conditionAnotequalsB($a,$b,$cell,$color = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_RED,$setBold = true){
    $objConditional = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Conditional();
    $objConditional->setConditionType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Conditional::CONDITION_EXPRESSION);
    echo '='.$a.'<>'.$b.'<br>';
    $objConditional->addCondition('='.$a.'<>'.$b);
    $objConditional->getStyle()->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB($color);
    $objConditional->getStyle()->getFont()->setBold($setBold);

    $this->addConditions($cell,$objConditional);
}
```

However the conditions - which look like this:

`='Trial Balance'!D12='Trial Balance'!E12
='Trial Balance'!D12<>'Trial Balance'!E12`

Generate the following error: `Balance Sheet!I10 -> 3D Range references are not yet supported`

This worked in PHPExcel but for some reason doesn't seem to work in PHPSpreadsheet. Is there something I need to change?

I haven't used the composer version but according to the change log is dated ## [1.1.0] - 2018-01-28. Is it a version issue? I would prefer not to have to use Composer.

Comment: The error message seems pretty explicit. The functionality that you used in PHPExcel is not yet implemented in PHPSpreadsheet. Why not just use PHPExcel?

Comment: Because I would like to use ODS writer abilities. I've also done a composer update but still the same result.

Comment: I have used neither library, but if PHPSpreadsheet can't handle range references to different sheets then it is not yet a mature library. `'Trial Balance'!D12` is nonproblematic in Excel itself, so an inability to deal with it is a serious drawback in a library designed to interface with Excel.

Comment: 3d ranges were never implemented in PHPExcel either.... although `'Trial Balance'!D12` isn't a 3d range reference, `'Trial Balance'!D12:E13` would be  3d range reference

Comment: Note that ods (OpenDocument) writer is abailable in PHPExcel as well as in PHPSpreadsheet, that's been the case for the last 10 years

Comment: Ah super and something I had obviously overlooked.

Comment: Hi Mark - the documentation here: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/10-Reading-and-Writing.md#openlibre-office-ods never mentioned an ODS writer which is why I didn't realise it was possible.

Comment: Plus the following: `PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($obj,'OpenDocument');` causes WAMP to crash.